# Replacing the /enchant command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Use /enchant to add an enchatement on a holding item with restriction (normal max enchant level, compatibility, enchantable item)

How can I add an enchant to an item I am holding(or what command to use in replacement)?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after 4 hours of commandblocking, I got this:
[image: Super RS CMD Block stuff]

Now to explain:

to activate this all, just use this command:

> /setblock *wool coords* minecraft:redstone_block

The CB #1 is to replace the redstone block with wool:

> /setblock *wool coords* minecraft:wool

The CB #2's make new scoreboard objectives:

> /scoreboard objectives add selectMe dummy
> /scoreboard objectives add selectMe2 dummy
> ...
> /scoreboard objectives add selectMe9 dummy

The #3's have this:

> /scoreboard players set @a selectMe 0
> ...
> /scoreboard players set @a selectMe9 0

The CB's labeled 4 use this commands:

> /scoreboard players set @a selectMe 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:TOOL1"}}
> ...
> /scoreboard players set @a selectMe9 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:TOOL9"}}

Now, the line tagged #5 has:

> /clear @a[score_selectMe_min=1] minecraft:TOOL1 0 1
> ...
> /clear @a[score_selectMe9_min=1] minecraft:TOOL9 0 1

Finally, those with #6:

> /give @a[score_selectMe_min=1] minecraft:TOOL1 1 0 {ench:[{id:ENCH_FOR_TOOL1,lvl:10}]}
> ...
> /give @a[score_selectMe9_min=1] minecraft:TOOL9 1 0 {ench:[{id:ENCH_FOR_TOOL9,lvl:10}]}

The 7-15 commands vary only in the items, enchant id's and scoreboard stuff:

7  - iron_helmet, 0, selectMe
8  - iron_chestplate, 0, selectMe2
9  - iron_leggings, 0, selectMe3
10 - iron_boots, 0, selectMe4
11 - iron_sword, 16, selectMe5
12 - bow, 48, selectMe6
13 - iron_shovel, 32, selectMe7
14 - iron_axe, 32, selectMe8
15 - iron_pickaxe, 32, selectMe9

This system will obvioulsy work only with certian (iron) items, will give only 1 enchant and will need for the Player to hold the item whilst entering the command - see higher.
So you would need to use a giant system for auto-executing a enchant, but if you just use the give command:

> **/give @p YOUR_TOOL 1 0 {ench:[{id:FIRST_ENCH_ID,lvl:2},{id:SECOND_ENCH_ID,lvl:30}]}**

Hope helped a bit.